# Alternative Proof for Exercise 7, p.62 of Patrick M. Fitzpatrick's Advanced Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that if $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)=0$ then there exits a number $x_0\in(0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ and and $f(x)>0$ if $0\leq x<x_0$; that is,there is a smallest point in the interval $\left[0,1\right]$ at which the function $f$ attains the value $0$.

Alright so the proof by contradiction follows easily from the assumption that there does not exist such an $x_0$. 
But I want to try a different way:

$f$ is continuous at $0$, therefore for $\epsilon=f(0)>0$ there exists $\delta$ such that $\left|f(x)-f(0)\right|<f(0)$ ie $0<f(x)<2f(0)$ for $0\leq x<\delta$. Now $\delta<1$ since $f(1)=0$ hence we can choose $x_0=\delta$, thus $f(x)>0$ if $0\leq x<x_0$.

Now here is the part where I got stuck: I have the intuition that due to our choice of $\epsilon=f(0)$, $f(0)=1$ and continuity of $f$ that $f(x_0)=0$. If we prove this then we are done. Now it is clear by continuity of $f$ that $f(x_0)\geq 0$ but does $f(x_0)>0$ generate a contradiction?

Comment: Am I missing something?  $f(1)=0$, so obviously there is a number $x_0\in (0,1]$ with $f(x_0)=0$.  But there is not necessarily any point for which $f<0$.  I'm on a "not so smart phone," and so a preemptive apology if I've misread.

Comment: Sorry was a typo, it's actually $f(x)>0$ for $0\leq x<x_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a semi-arbitrary $\delta$ (if $\delta$ works so does $\delta/2$) so you cannot conclude that $f(x_0)=0$.  If you worked with the sup of the $\delta$ then the proof could be pushed through.

**Added:** Here is a proof somewhat along the lines you described, that in a sense uses the supremum of the $\delta$.

Let $S$ be the set of all $x$ in our interval such that $f(t)\gt 0$ for all $t$ with $0< t< x$. Then $S$ is non-empty and bounded above, so has a supremum $x_0$. If $x_0=1$ we are finished. So suppose that $x_0\lt 1$ and $f(x_0)\gt 0$. Then by continuity there is a positive $\epsilon$ such that $f(t)\gt 0$ for all $t$ with $x_0\lt t\lt x_0+\epsilon$, contradicting the fact that $x_0$ is the supremum of $S$.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: Sketch: Let $S$ be the set of all $x$ such that $f(t)\gt 0$ for all $t$ with $0\le t\lt x$. Then $S$ has a supremum $x_0$. If $x_0=1$ we are finished. If $x_0\lt 1$, by continuity there is an interval about $x_0$ in which the function is positive, contradicting the fact that $x_0$ is the sup of $S$.

Comment: Alright this works! Can you post the sketch as an answer please so I can accept the answer?